# how to accelerate compute for pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The source data is event logs from device and all data is json format,
sample of raw json data

```
{"sn": "123", "ip": null, "evt_name": "client_requestData", "evt_content": {"count": 1, "hour": 13, "dow": 0, "segmentation": {"requestService": "music", "requestData": "is_online", "requestOpcode": "get_state"}, "sum": 0}, "evt_ts": 1521350052, "app_key": "f6e7f4f8ec4b4d6dae6fa2b5ed8f90cb6a640759", "sdk_name": "countlysdk_0.0.9", "sdk_version": "17.05"}
{"sn": "123", "ip": null, "evt_name": "client_requestData2", "evt_content": {"count": 1, "hour": 13, "dow": 0, "segmentation": {"requestService": "fm", "requestData": "is_online", "requestOpcode": "get_state"}, "sum": 0}, "evt_ts": 1521350053, "app_key": "f6e7f4f8ec4b4d6dae6fa2b5ed8f90cb6a640759", "sdk_name": "countlysdk_0.0.9", "sdk_version": "17.05"}
{"sn": "123", "ip": null, "evt_name": "client_requestData3", "evt_content": {"count": 1, "hour": 13, "dow": 0, "segmentation": {"requestService": "video", "requestData": "is_online", "requestOpcode": "get_state"}, "sum": 0}, "evt_ts": 1521350054, "app_key": "f6e7f4f8ec4b4d6dae6fa2b5ed8f90cb6a640759", "sdk_name": "countlysdk_0.0.9", "sdk_version": "17.05"}
{"sn": "123", "ip": null, "evt_name": "client_requestData4", "evt_content": {"count": 1, "hour": 13, "dow": 0, "segmentation": {"requestService": "fm", "requestData": "is_online", "requestOpcode": "get_state"}, "sum": 0}
```

I have a event list,eg: tar_task_list, about 100 and more items,and for each event
I need to aggregate all the event from the raw data and then save this to a event csv file

Below is code

```
#read source data
raw_data = sc.textFile("s3://xxx").map(lambda x:json.loads(x))
# TODO: NEED TO SPEED UP THIS COMPUTING
for tar_evt_name in evts:
    print("...")
    table_name = out_table_prefix + tar_evt_name
    evt_one_rdd = raw_data.filter(lambda x: x.get("evt_name") == tar_evt_name)
    evt_one_rdd.cache()
    evt_one_dict = evt_one_rdd.first()
    Evt_one = Row(*sorted(['{}'.format(k) for k, v in evt_one_dict.items()]))

    col_len = len(evt_one_rdd.first())
    evt_one_rdd2 = evt_one_rdd.map(lambda x: to_list(x, col_len)).filter(lambda x: len(x) is not 0)
    evt_one_rdd2.cache()
    df = spark.createDataFrame(evt_one_rdd2.map(lambda x: Evt_one(*x)))
    out_csv_path = output + '/' + tar_evt_name+'/'# add last '/' for copy err
    df.write.csv(out_csv_path, mode='overwrite', header=True,sep='|',nullValue="NULL")
```

the output data like below:
time : 2018-05-07 00:03|8dab4796-fa37-4114-0011-7637fa2b0001|f6e7f4f8ec4b4d6dae6fa2b5ed8f90cb6a640759|0.2.23|131074|2018-05-08 23:24:25|0|false|default|2.4.130

Comment: Can you provide an example of input data and what the expected output is to go along with your code sample?

Comment: I just update how read the input data

Comment: Can provide an actual sample of the input data? It will be much easier to try and help you.

Comment: raw data is just json data,and I upload 5 items , my py script is about 800,000 line this logs, about 1GBytes.I user aws EMR to process this raw data and my instance is m4.large, I just user 1 master and 4 slave,my emr step will run about 4hours,I want speed up this running,hope someone will give me some advice.Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt,

I have noticed a few issues here,

- `for tar_evt_name in evts` is a native Python for loop, which incur a performance penalty when it seems like you want to do a group by operation;
- `.cache()` is used, but seemingly for no reason;
- Unsure what `to_list` is;
- Don't think `evt_one_rdd2.map(lambda x: Evt_one(*x)))` works;

  ```
  import json
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  from pyspark.sql import Row
  from pyspark.sql import Window

  raw_data = sc.textFile('test.txt')

  df = raw_data.map(
      # Map the raw input to python dict using `json.loads`
      json.loads,
  ).map(
      # Duplicate the evt_name and evt_ts for later use in a Row object
      lambda x: Row(evt_name=x['evt_name'], evt_ts=x.get('evt_ts', 1), data=x),
  ).toDF()  # Convert into a dataframe...
  # ... (I am actually unusre if this is faster...
  # ... but I am more comfortable with this)

  filtered_df = df.withColumn(
      # NOTE: Assumed you want the first row, as you used `evt_one_rdd.first()`.
      #       So we assign a row number (named rn) and then filter on rn = 1.
      #       Here the evt_name and evt_ts becomes handy, you might want to set
      #       your own evt_ts properly.
      'rn', F.row_number().over(
          Window.partitionBy(df['evt_name']).orderBy(df['evt_ts'])
      ),
  ).filter('rn = 1').where(
      # NOTE: Since you used `map(lambda x: to_list(x, col_len)).filter(lambda x: len(x) is not 0)`,
      #       I assume you meant data should have more than 0 keys,
      #       but this should be almost always true?
      #       Since you are grouping by `evt_name`, which means
      #       there is at least that key most of the time.
      F.size(F.col('data')) > 0
  )

  filtered_df.write(....)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, and after I try it found that this solution is great